# Read from /proc/<pid>

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler, procfs

I understand, I think, that when reading from disk, the process gets put into uninterruptible sleep while disk IO is performed. But what happens during procfs readouts? The process goes into D state, but shouldn't it just keep running and complete instantly? There is no intensive hardware interaction, right?

Comment: Reading from procfs is basically like making a system call. It shouldn't go into D state.

Comment: Thanks, this sheds some new light. That means that, under RT patch (fully preemptive), it can get preempted? I assume that, even in that case, the lock it has on a procfs file will be kept until it gets rescheduled?

Comment: There's no real file, I don't see why it would need to lock it.

Comment: Hm, but how can that be? What if kernel is updating data in procfs while my process is reading it? It is very interesting, though, because sometimes I get hung_task messages because ps or top are stuck in sys_read (stack trace showing D state) while rcu thread is trying to acquire rt-mutex from them..

Comment: You should probably look at the code of the procfs driver. There may be some kind of mutex on the kernel data structures, but it's not a file lock.

Comment: `procfs` is basically just a collection of functions that create formatted output from kernel structures.

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is the function I am looking for? static int proc_readfd_common(struct file *file, struct dir_context *ctx,    instantiate_t instantiate) Located in linux/fs/proc/fd.c. I see that the code in it is protected with rcu_read_lock() so I will investigate from there. I guess it explains why RCU thread would try and get a lock on ps; maybe it has to do some syncing (I am not that good with RCU). Perhaps somewhere there it leads to D state.